# Text in Custom QQuickItem

Tags: qt, qtquick2

I am implementing a Custom QQuickItem which should be able to make a lineplot (x vs y). For performance reasons I did this using QSGNodes. I wonder what is the best way to implement the Text-Labels for the x-ticks (they should get set automatically according to the data range).

Should I use a QQuickPaintedItem or is there a way to do it via the QQuickItem?

Or is it possible to dynamically create text qml types ( http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html) in my c++ file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't over-complicate things by reinventing wheels. QML already has a `Text` type.

There is a downside - the decision to not have a public API to use the QML types from C++ in their C++ form. And I would not recommend creating QML objects from C++, it is just counterproductive.

Which means that your custom QML type will not be implemented purely in C++, you can implement the "core" stuff in C++ and still compose the complete type on the QML side, where you also get to use bindings, anchors, models, positioners, dynamic scoping and all that good stuff that is hard to do in C++.

This is not uncommon, lots of the stock QML controls are implemented this way - an abstract C++ core exposed to QML, where it is finished into a complete control in QML syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you give me a pointer how this would be done on the qml side? Let's assume my c++ class has a function which can return a list of tick positions. How would I generate the labels in qml?

Comment: @numberCruncher take a look at implementing `QAbstractListModel` on the C++ side, and then in QML you have stuff like `ListView` or `Repeater` which automatically instantiate a defined visual object and associate it with the data model.

Comment: Doing this in QML will allow you to have a lot of dynamism in changing the design and appearance, and will save you **a lot** of time comapred to doing it in C++.